# How do I use objects in controller for viewing data in Rails 4 devise sign_in page

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have a controller called UserController and then in users/sign_in ,I am having my login page in that I want to show a list of users already signed up in the site .

Since Sign_in is not an action defined in the controller , Where do I Create and Assign data to the object such that I can retrieve it and display in my sign_in page .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Called the Table inside Devise sign_in page like

```
<%= @object = Table.all %>
```

This worked for me I was able to show records from Table in the sign_in page.